# Redirecting a domain works on HTTP but not on HTTPS with IIS server

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, https, iis

We built a site for a client to advertise a new block of apartments they had built.  The apartments have now all been sold so we have been asked to forward the domain to another domain until there is a future use for it.

We have tried to do this by setting up a 301 redirect on our server - this works great for HTTP requests (both with and without WWW) but HTTPS requests fail.  Can anyone offer us any tips?

here are the 2 web config files we have tried:

**WEB CONFIG 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to http" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(/\w*[/ | \w]+\.aspx)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>

<location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect destination="https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk/" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

**WEB CONFIG 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk/" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Paul, what are you seeing happening in your browser's developer tools - i.e., Console and Network tabs?

Comment: Do you have a security certificate?  You need to get a certificate for HTTPS to work.   It can be a free one from LetsEncrypt using their automated verification process.  Or you can pay for one.

Answer (score 1):

WEB CONFIG 1

change rewrite action url protocol to HTTPS and add new forwarding domain (redirects 1:1 -- http://old-domain.co.uk/link <> https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk/link)

`<action type="Redirect" url="https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />`

or redirect all requests to https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk/ homepage

`<action type="Redirect" url="https://WEBFORWARDINGDOMAIN.co.uk/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />`